# Excluding directories for a single Visual Studio C++ project

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008

I have a large set of include directories for my solution, and want to exclude one of them for a single project in the solution, how can I do this?

Comment: Why do you need to exclude them? They don't add to compilation time unless you're including files from that directory.

Comment: Including one of these directories leads to compiler facing ambiguity while trying to resolve a user defined data type. All the other projects in the solution need this directory, just this one project doesn't.

Comment: The header files from that (or any) directory are not included unless you `#include` them. I don't understand how there could be any ambiguity with regard to types if the headers that define those types are not included.

Comment: I have a path in the Include Dirs section of my VCComponents.dat so all the header files in this path are included by default for all projects. This is required for building majority of the projects in my solution.
For one particular project, this include leads to "
error C2872: 'xyz' : ambiguous symbol"
even though there is no #include for any file in the affecting path.
Removing the path from VCComponents.dat allows the project to build successful, but makes other projects fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to exclude an include for a single project in the solution (after conversation with folks at MSDN). The best workaround is to not inherit from solution for that one specific project, and to define its includes at the project level, without the directory that was causing problems.